# sqlite c++ parse row or get value by column name

Tags: c++, sqlite

Look at the following part of code. Here I `SELECT` whole table. Then I want to parse every row and receive table content by column name. is it possible with `SQLite` to access column at the row by name? thanks

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, buffer, strlen(buffer), &stmt, 0) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    int cols = sqlite3_column_count(stmt);
    int result = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        result = sqlite3_step(stmt);

            if(result == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                 // want to get result by column name xxx['columnName'];
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that directly, but it's easy enough to get the name of a column by index: `std::string col_name( sqlite3_column_name(stmt,column_index) );`

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to show us with that code.  It doesn't show us anything.  If you want to get by column name, why not just name the column in your SELECT statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over all column numbers and call [sqlite3_column_name](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_name.html) for each one, checking whether the name matches.

A much cleaner design would be to use not `SELECT *` but

```sql
SELECT list, the, column, names, here FROM ...
```

and then use the *known* column indexes (0...4) directly with [sqlite3_column_*type*](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html).

---

Using `sqlite3_column_name` should be necessary only when you're executing some *unknown* query that you got from outside your program.

Comment: many thanks. i understand the trick :) i am new at sqlite. ps. for my skill: when I use `SELECT *` indexes is unavailable?

Comment: With `SELECT *`, you get the same column names as if you had written the columns out. The problem is that you do not immediately know them, especially if the table structure changes later.